# start actions after sending response java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, asynchronous

I want to start a time consuming process after sending a response in java spring boot application. I am not able to get an exact example of implementation.

Example code is given below: I want to simulate similar

```
@POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public PutObjectResult uploadFile(@FormDataParam("files") InputStream file, @FormDataParam("files") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
            PutObjectResult putObjectResult = this.coreModule.save(file, fileDetail);
            if (putObjectResult != null) {
                return putObjectResult;
            }
            return new PutObjectResult();
            //i want this time consuming process to not block my response. basically i am doing it for high user experience.
            TimeConsumingProcess timeConsumingProcess = new TimeConsumingProcess();
            timeConsumingProcess.start();
    }
```

I know that execution after return is not correct. But i want to simulate a very similar action. Probably i think performing a completable future might be a good idea so that is not blocking my return statement, but i am thinking if there is an elegant way of handling a situation like this!!!!

Comment: This [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) should help. (Remove the part about waiting for the tasks to complete.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, let me look at it whether I am able to simulate the expected behavior.